# Setting up Network (TCP) Load balancer for GCE instances with Container-Optimized OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I have a containerized server, which is running on GCE (using Container-optimized OS feature). Now that the server is running, I am trying to set up a load balancer between my server and clients, but setting up load balancer requires me to create a start script, which only works on [Debian OS](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/setting-up-network-backend-service#setting_up_the_instances). At the end of the day, I just need my server to be load balanced over TLS.

1. My server serves RPCs over port 8080, do I need the startup script provided in the GCP document?

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2 -y
a2ensite default-ssl
a2enmod ssl
vm_hostname="$(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor:Google" \
http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/name)"
echo "Page served from: $vm_hostname" | \
tee /var/www/html/index.html
systemctl restart apache2
```

2. If I do need it, how do I use `apt-get` on Container-Optimized OS?

Answer (score 1):

Google Compute Engine Container Optimized OS (COS) is locked down. You do not have tools such as apt that modify the host operating system. Instead, deploy a container-based application.

The script in your question is an example for demonstration purposes with Compute Engine and does not apply to COS.